# how do I fill my 2d array to the same values

Tags: java, javafx

I want all of the buttons on my grid to change from blank to X to O and then back to blank every time they are clicked. it currently only works for the first element in the array as the values of I and j are both 0. Do I need a loop similar to where I initialise the buttons?

I though the two nested for loops were what I need to add, however I have tried this and it has worked.

Any suggestions?

Comment: You can use [`Arrays.fill`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#fill(java.lang.Object[],%20int,%20int,%20java.lang.Object)) : `for (Foo[] array : my2dArray) { Arrays.fill(array, someValue); }`

Comment: where abouts would that go in my program?

Comment: Forget that comment. You need to use different instances of `Button`.

Comment: So a different instance for each array location?

Comment: A different instance for every button you want to add to the scene. You cannot add the same node to a scene more than once.

Comment: Is there no shorter way? your suggestion would end of with 25 instances in this example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use final fields `i` and `j` are used to set the event handler. If you want all the buttons to use handle the click the same way, you need to register the event handler to every button.

Since you can only access effectively final variables inside the loop you need to make a final copy of the loop variables or simply declare a local variable for the `Button`.

```
final List<String> values = Arrays.asList("", "X", "O");

for(int i=0; i<btn.length; i++){
    for(int j=0; j<btn.length;j++){
        final Button button = new Button("");

        button.setOnAction(event -> {
            int valueIndex = values.indexOf(button.getText());
            button.setText(values.get((valueIndex+1) % values.size()));
        });
        // Initializing 2D buttons with values i,j
        btn[i][j] = button;                      
        button.setPrefSize(35, 40);
        gridPane.add(button, i, j);
        // button.setDisable(false);
    }
}
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You can define a single event handler and assign it to all your buttons in your loop

```
EventHandler<ActionEvent> eventHandler = new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                 Button button = (Button) event.getSource();

                 switch (button.getText()) {
                    case "":
                      button.setText("X");
                      break;
                    case "X":
                      button.setText("O");
                      break;
                    default:
                      button.setText("");
                      break;
                }
            }
        };

//Two FOR loops used for creating 2D array of buttons with values    i,j
for(int i=0; i<btn.length; i++){
        for(int j=0; j<btn.length;j++){

           // Initializing 2D buttons with values i,j
           btn[i][j] = new Button();                      
           btn[i][j].setPrefSize(35, 40);
           gridPane.add(btn[i][j], i, j);
           btn[i][j].setText("");
           btn[i][j].setDisable(false);

           btn[i][j].setOnAction(eventHandler);
        }        
}
```

Comment: This is a JavaFX question. But irrespective of that, why do it this way? You can add event handlers to each button in the loop where they are created, and avoid the ugly downcast from the source of the event.

Comment: @James_D Changed JButton to Button. My bad.

Comment: @James_D In relation with your other statements ... You can define the anonymous event handler in its own class and create a new instance in the loop (you are right in this point). As you have detected, I come from Swing, there is no such uglyness in a simple downcast. That subjective IMHO.